# Javascript custom configrmation message SweetAlert.js

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I want to show a custom confirmation message in my ASP.NET MVC application.

After some search, I found SweetAlert which is a very nice tool.

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

I want to define a javascript method in a js file which calls the sweetalert to show a dialog.

But the document doesn't wait for the respons of the client.

To demonstrate what I mean, I added the code below.

The code alert("Doesn't wait"); executes before sweetalert shows its message.

My objectif is to add a custom javascript file and define a simble function to call and return true or false to avoid typing all the code below in every confirmation case.
As it doesn't wait the client interaction, I don't know if it is possible.

Any idea ?

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="SweetAlert.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="customConfirm();">Confirm</button>
    </body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">

   function customConfirm(){
    Swal.fire({
    title: 'myTitle',
    text: 'my Question',
    type: 'question',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: 'rgb(181, 212, 83)',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'YES'
   }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
   });

   alert("doesn't wait.");
  }

   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform all checks in the callback.

```
   function customConfirm(callback){
    Swal.fire({
    title: 'myTitle',
    text: 'my Question',
    type: 'question',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: 'rgb(181, 212, 83)',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'YES'
   }).then((result) => {
    // Do some stuff and call the callback
    callback();
    if (result.value) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
   });
```

In another file:

```
customConfirm(function() { 
    // Put some stuff you want to do 
});
```

Or:

```
function callbackDoSomething() {}
customConfirm(callbackDoSomething);
```

Comment: Does it mean that it is not possible what I want ?

Comment: No it means that the alert is fired immediately because it is not defined in the callback. Just try it and see what gives.

Comment: Very nice, and it works like this. But I couldn't explain my problem. In fact I want to define a javascript method in a javascript file to avoid typing all this code in all confirmation messages. I edit my question.